# How to make nant complain when a file is missing from a fileset

Tags: nant, fileset

I have a `fileset` element in a build file that is defined as:

```
<fileset id="fileset" basedir=".">
    <include name="test.txt"/>
    <include name="missing.txt"/>
</fileset>
```

When this runs (as part of a copy task), it does not complain if any of the files are missing. Whilst I can use `failonempty="true"` in the `fileset` element, this only fails if **both** files are missing.

I can achieve this by making multiple filesets with `failonempty="true"` set, each one containing a single file, but this feels clunky. This is also a maintenance problem if there are lots of required files.

Is there any way of making nant complain if **any** of the files in the fileset are missing? If this is not possible, is there another way of achieving the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add attribute `asis="true"`:

```
<fileset id="fileset" basedir=".">
  <include name="test.txt" asis="true" />
  <include name="missing.txt" asis="true" />
</fileset>
```

NAnt will complain then in case the file is missing.

Comment: I had already seen and tried that and it didn't work. Not sure what I was doing wrong as I tried it again and it now works.